# oracle matrix report filling null cells

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have made a matrix report in oracle report builder like this

[image]

And here is my query from which report is being calling

```
SELECT A.p_date,
       L.sup_name,
       Decode(A.perc_typ, 1, 'Buff',
                          2, 'Cow')     PERC_TYPE,
       A.sup_rate                       RATE,
       Decode(A.perc_typ,
       1, Round(( Nvl(A.fat_perc, 0) * Nvl(A.gross_vol, 0) ) / 6, 5),
       2, Round(
          ( Nvl(A.fat_perc, 0) + (
            ( Nvl(A.fat_perc, 0) * 0.22 ) + (
            Nvl(A.lr_perc, 0) * 0.25 ) + 0.72 ) ) *
          Nvl(A.gross_vol, 0) / 13, 5)) VOL
FROM   mlk_purchase A,
       supplier L
WHERE  A.sup_cod = L.sup_cod
       AND A.p_date <= Trunc(SYSDATE)
       AND a.p_date >= Trunc(SYSDATE) - 7
ORDER  BY 1
```

Problem is that there are are showing empty cells where no data is coming from query. I want to show zero cells instead of empty space. Is there any way to do this in oracle report builder.

Comment: use the nvl function?

Comment: Can you share the query result?

Comment: Or you can also use `NVL2( string1, value_if_NOT_null, value_if_null )` to alter the results of the query ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two solutions.

**Solution 1** -- In Oracle Reports, create a boilerplate text object that displays the zero, and arrange this object so that it displays behind the matrix field.  This way, the boilerplate is hidden when the field is displayed, but is revealed when the field is not displayed.  This solution is described in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/bi.1111/b32122/orbr_matrix006.htm#i1012231).

**Solution 2** -- Rewrite your query to return rows with zero values for combinations of your row and column fields that have no data.  For example, you might find all the possible combinations of the matrix row and column fields (supplier and date in this case), outer join your data to the combinations, and use NVL to convert null values to zeroes.  It might look something like this:

```
SELECT
    L.P_DATE,
    L.SUP_NAME,
    DECODE(A.PERC_TYP, 1, 'Buff', 2, 'Cow') PERC_TYPE,
    A.SUP_RATE RATE,
    NVL
    (
        DECODE
        (
            A.PERC_TYP, 
            1, 
            ROUND
            (
                (NVL(A.FAT_PERC, 0) * NVL(A.GROSS_VOL, 0)) / 6,
                5
            ),
            2,
            ROUND
            (
                (NVL(A.FAT_PERC, 0) + 
                    (
                        (NVL(A.FAT_PERC, 0) * 0.22) + 
                        (NVL(A.LR_PERC, 0) * 0.25) + 0.72)
                    ) * NVL(A.GROSS_VOL, 0) / 13,
                5
            )
        ),
        0
    ) VOL
FROM
    MLK_PURCHASE A,
    (
        SELECT
            L1.SUP_CODE,
            L1.SUP_NAME,
            L2.P_DATE
        FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    SUPPLIER.SUP_CODE, 
                    SUPPLIER.SUP_NAME 
                FROM 
                    SUPPLIER
            ) L1,
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    MLK_PURCHASE.P_DATE
                FROM
                    MLK_PURCHASE
                WHERE
                    MLK_PURCHASE.P_DATE <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
                    AND
                    MLK_PURCHASE.P_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 7
            ) L2
    ) L
WHERE 
    A.SUP_COD (+) = L.SUP_COD
    AND
    A.P_DATE (+) = L.P_DATE
ORDER BY
    1
```

A more efficient (and simpler) way to rewrite the query to the same effect might be to use a [partitioned outer join](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28314/tdpdw_sql.htm#CIHFDGIA) between `MLK_PURCHASE` and `SUPPLIER` that partitions by `SUP_CODE`, but I don't know to what extent your version of Oracle Reports supports this syntax.